# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xib

[image]

I have a custom xib file and am trying to load a picture when the table view is launched. However I get this error of multiple constraints. I have set the row height of the tableviewcell automatic, and the sum of three views that comprise the xib view add up to 408 pixels. I have also tried setting the row height to 409 given the error said 408.333 pixels for the cell, however this did not help.

Comment: Can you add the list of constraints? One of your constraints says stackView.top == UIView.top.. maybe check that one.

Comment: Assuming you have your constraints setup correctly (if the output looks correct, then you probably do), set the stackView's bottom constraint Priority to 999 -- it's a common issue.

Comment: Changing the priority to 999 worked! Thank you. If this is a common issue, apple should give it a look.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a common issue, ***particularly*** when using `UIStackView`s in table view cells.

The problem is that as auto-layout is "doing its thing," it has to make several passes to calculate the complete layout.

When it encounters a stack view in a (non-fixed-height) cell, it needs to deal with the various heights of the stackView's arranged subviews, the table width and height, and the cell height. In addition, because a ***point*** on a `@2x` scale device uses 2 pixels, and on a `@3x` scale device it uses 3 pixels, auto-layout has to manipulate heights around one-half-points and one-third-points, respectively.

I think I would say it's not surprising that *at some point during those calculations* auto-layout prints error / warning messages to the console.

Setting the `Priority` on the stack view's Bottom constraint to `999` allows auto-layout to, I guess, *temporarily* break the constraint without coughing up the warning.

So... is it a Bug? Or is it Unavoidable? Only Apple knows for sure. :)